# Proxy nginx to ingress-nginx for migration purpose

Tags: curl, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

## context

I'm migrating from traditional docker host to kubernetes cluster.

I want to have a continuity of service during that migration.

For that purpose, I proxy the local nginx to the remote ingress-nginx. Then, I update dns records. This is nice setup for 2 reasons:

- the traffic continues to flow while the dns propagates
- I can generate a let's encrypt cert in the ingress-nginx, so once the dns propagated, my clients are served with proper cert

In the mean time the cert is not generated, nginx will get served the default self-signed cert. I know it, so I want to verify against this, but I can't manage to do it.

### minimum issue

Without discussing much about nginx configuration, we can reproduce the issue with curl only.

This is how I get the remote self-signed cert:

`openssl s_client -showcerts -servername standard.ingress.indie.host -connect standard.ingress.indie.host:443 < /dev/null | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/ p' > server.pem`

And I expect the following command to work:

`curl --cacert ./server.pem https://standard.ingress.indie.host`

But it doesn't.. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, if you could help, it would be awesome! Thanks!

PS: this is the real host, so you can test against, the issue is live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two things preventing that `curl` command from working, in this order:

1. `X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical CA:FALSE`
2. `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: DNS:ingress.local`

The `O=Acme Co, CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate` certificate is not a CA, it's just self-signed. Therefore, (as I understand it) *no* value of `--cacert` would represent the "parent" in the X509 hierarchy and enable curl to trust the CA cert's child certificates.

However, even if there was a hypothetical issuing CA for that certificate, it is only issued for a SAN of `ingress.local`, which `standard.ingress.indie.host` definitely does not match.

I can't tell from your question whether `curl --insecure` is an option for you, or you are merely using curl to indicate the bad SSL outcome that is happening for the browsers (who don't easily have `--insecure`).

---

Having said that, I believe it would be possible to actually generate a fake CA, and then issue a certificate against it, install that in nginx and then feed the fake CA to `curl --cafile` (or, if required, install the CA into the trusted certificate store of the OS).

Please do follow up if there are more specifics you would find helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insight. I think you nailed it down. My main concern is to verify the identity of the upstream server. I don't want to use `insecure` flag. I'm curious now, and I'll try both to see which parameter is important for curl.